# Quick introduction to manifold theory for Riemannian Geometry at level of Lee/Petersen?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I'm taking a course on Riemannian geometry using Lee and Petersen, and I'm falling a bit behind mostly because it has been a long time since I thought about differential geometry.

I took a course on differential geometry using do Carmo about two years ago, and remember a little bit, but it did not cover much manifold theory (and did not talk about tangent spaces, derivations, connections, differentials, etc).

Is there a good text that has a reasonably concise introduction to the essentials of manifold theory that I'd need to survive and get something out of the Riemannian geometry course? I've got a fairly strong analysis/ point-set topology and algebra background; it's mostly the geometry aspect that I'm lacking. I've been relying on Bishop/Goldberg's Tensor Analysis on Manifolds to get by, but am wondering if there are other (consise) texts/sets of notes I should be looking at.

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395/reading-list-for-basic-differential-geometry).

Comment: What do you think of Lee's book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds? Another great book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Tu.

Comment: I think that the linked MO question is not quite as specific as my post. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds is quite lengthy, so I'd be looking for something shorter. I'm not familiar with the Tu book.

Comment: Take a look at Boothby's *Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry*.